# How to export kableExtra output in R to Word?

Tags: r, ms-word, kableextra, modelsummary

I created a summary table of my models in `R` with the package `modelsummary` and then customized the look with the `kableExtra` package.

`tab<-modelsummary(welfarestate,stars=c("*"=.1,"**"=.05,"***"=.01),statistic="std.error",title="WVS Welfarestate",output = "kableExtra",notes=list("*p<0.1, **p<0.05, ***p<0.1"),add_rows = rows_welfarestate)`

`tab%>%kable_styling(c("striped","hover"),font_size = 20)`

What ist the best way to integrate the output in the `R` Viewer window into a Word document without losing the formatting?

I found the information that it should be possible to copy the html output generated by `kableExtra` from the Viewer in `R` directly into a Word document. However,when I simply copy and paste nothing is displayed in my Word document. And copying from the html output in a web browser doesnt keep the formattig. Just creating a png loses some quality somehow.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`kableExtra` does not support output to Word documents. As you noted, we can save the table to an HTML file, either with `modelsummary()`'s `output` argument, or with `kableExtra`'s `save_kable()` function. Then, you can open the document in Word, but you will almost certainly lose special formatting and styling.

In my view, if you need a Word table, the best option is to use `flextable` output instead of `kableExtra`. In `modelsummary` you can do that by saving to a `.docx` file directly:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(flextable)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

modelsummary(mod, output = "table.docx")
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the many `flextable` customization functions. For example:

```r
modelsummary(mod, output = "flextable") |>
    theme_zebra() |>
    save_as_docx(path = "table.docx")
```

Note that `flextable` is super flexible. See their documentation: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will have a closer look at the `flextable` package. I was just confused because the option of copy/paste from `R` to Word and keep formatting (even without creating a docx file) is even mentioned in the official documentation site: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/    in the section "kabelExtra and Word".  But if `flextable` allows me to customize the table and save it as a docx file, without having to do too much post formatting in Word, that should be enough.

Comment: I've personally not had much success with this HTML to Word strategy, but your mileage may vary. The video you link to looks compelling...

Comment: It looks super compelling. I even saw a person mentioning in another forum that it worked for them. But somehow it doesnt in my case (maybe I should ask the package creator). As exporting a png from the R viewer gives me the exact output I want to have and is easy to integrate into Word, you dont coincidentilly know how to avoid the slight quality loss of this procedure?

Comment: No, sorry. I've tried all the options that seemed vaguely DPI-related but couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I guess I have to switch to R Markdown/Latex at one point as things seem to be much more easy to integrate there.